# Dynamic Color Of seekbar on run time in android

Tags: android, dynamic, background-color, seekbar, android-progressbar

I am working on a android application. I need dynamic color on run time of progressed bar.It will depend upon then theme selected by user.Like if user selected red theme then progressed seek bar should be red.If he selected yellow them then color of progressed seek bar should be yellow.
I have tried through

seekbar.setProgressDrawable(new ColorDrawable(R.color.red));

but its not working please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: Is the seekbar in the same activity as your theme selection user interface?

Answer (score 0):

```
int mColor = prefs.getInt("color_prefs", Color.RED);
mSeekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(mColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

it works fine for me.

Comment: You may want to add a mutate() call to this. Because the Drawable could be used by more than one seekbar at a time.